# How to Hide API key in Preact?

Tags: api, process, environment-variables, preact

How can i hide api key in preact , in react i used .env file , but don't know how to do it in preact ?

```
index.js?2e9b:8 Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: process is not defined
    at eval (index.js?2e9b:8)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at asyncGeneratorStep (index.js:5)
    at _next (index.js:7)
    at eval (index.js:7)
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at eval (index.js:7)
    at getSeriesInfo (index.js?2e9b:7)
    at Object.eval [as __] (index.js?2e9b:14)
    at j (index.js?a178:361)
```

Answer (score 1):

Preact is just a UI library, but I'll assume you're referring to Preact-CLI, which is an actual build tool. Let me know if this is incorrect.

Our wiki covers this under "[Use Environment Variables in your Application](https://github.com/preactjs/preact-cli/wiki/Config-Recipes#use-environment-variables-in-your-application)". `process` will not exist outside of Node so you'll need to specify the variables you want to use using `DefinePlugin`.

Add the following to your `preact.config.js` file:

```js
export default (config, env, helpers) => {
    config.plugins.push(
        new helpers.webpack.DefinePlugin({
            'process.env.MY_VARIABLE': JSON.stringify('my-value'),
        }),
    );
};
```

If you specifically want to read from a `.env` file, you will also need to add some utility to read it, such as `dotenv`:

```js
import dotenv from 'dotenv';

dotenv.config();

export default (config, env, helpers) => {
    config.plugins.push(
        new helpers.webpack.DefinePlugin({
            'process.env.MY_VARIABLE': JSON.stringify(process.env.MY_VARIABLE),
        }),
    );
};
```